# Store a css class on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My project has the option to change the site theme by clicking on a link:

```
<ul>
  <li class="=contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="facebook"><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
  <li class="twitter"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
  <li class="rss"><a href="#">Feed Rss</a></li>
  <li class="change-theme"><a href="#">Change Theme</a></li>
</ul>
```

When clicked on the link within the `<li class="change-theme">` it's trigger the script:

```
$('.change-theme').click(function () {
  $('body').toggleClass('theme-dark');
});
```

It's add the class `theme-dark`, changing the site theme. But when the user refresh the page, the default theme comes back.
There is a way to store the theme chosen and use it even when the browser is updated?

Comment: Have you looked into cookies, sessions, etc?

Comment: You would need to use localStorage, cookies, or an AJAX request to a back end datastore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Localstorage will provide you a possibilty to store the data without expiration-date:

```
$('.change-theme').click(function () {
    $('body').toggleClass('theme-dark');
    if($('body').hasClass('theme-dark')){
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'theme-dark');
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');  
    if(theme !== ''){      
        $('body').addClass(theme);
    }
});
```

Whereas `sessionStorage` will store the data only for one session, until the browser is closed (usage is the same as `localStorage`).

All major Browser support this feature, the Internet Explorer support this since version 8.

**Note:** you can only store strings in the Webstorage.

If you want to use cookies instead you can try:

```
document.cookie="theme=theme-dark"; //setter
```

and

```
var x = document.cookie; //getter
```

**Reference**

[webStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

[cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)